# Install Thunar 4.17.8 in XUbuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, ppa, xfce

I tried to add the ppa https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/kinetic/+source/thunar but it says it does not exist, and I don't exactly know how to use that branch of that ppa to upgrade my thunar to the newest version without having to install the 22.10 preview

```
jonathan@hellion:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/thunar
[sudo] password for jonathan: 
ERROR: ppa 'ubuntu/thunar' not found (use --login if private)
```

Do you know if it is possible ?

Comment: I'm confused; you provided a non-PPA launchpad link, yet your question talks about a PPA? What OS & release are you using, as *kinetic* is currently off-topic.  FYI:  The version of `thunar` you appear to what is what I have installed; no PPA was required  -- but your issue is confusion about what launchpad is; it's a lot more than just PPAs and what you're chasing isn't a personal package archive, but the main *kinetic* packages built for daily ISOs, or *kinetic* installs via `apt` etc.

Comment: Basically, I am on Jammy Jellyfish which has Thunar 4.16.x version and I would like to get the 4.17.x, so I want to switch from the Jellyfish to Kinetic for only that specific package.

Comment: Which means installing `thunar` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/thunar) and all it's requirements from *kinetic* too where *jammy* has no suitable requirements; ie. you want to move your system off LTS & make it part *kinetic*?  You're willing to no longer be LTS (esp. Xfce components)... I don't see that much change, but I'd still recommend against it for security reasons (you'll need to manually patch) even though possible  (*there are links to download binary on the page in your question if you follow them; but don't forget you'll need more than just `thunar`*)